# Pagination stuck on page. Python web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, pagination, python-3.9

Im trying to scrape a list of Japanese companies. It works fine until it gets to a certain page and then starts repeating over it again and again. I'm a web scraping noob so apologies in advance. I have attached a png of the error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cviDA.png)

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

l = []

for x in range(1,999): 

   url= 'https://jpn.bizdirlib.com/company?page='
   r=requests.get(url+str(x))

   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")


   all= soup.find_all('span', class_='field-content')



   for item in all: 
    
     name = item.find('a').text

     Company_info = {'name': name}

     l.append(Company_info)

   print('companies found:', len(l))
   time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('companies.csv')
```

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text into the reddit message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: What is the certain page it gets stuck on?  Why do you think it gets stuck there?

Comment: thank you for the feedback. it gets stuck on different pages. Before it was getting stuck on page 36, sometimes its a different page. I thought maybe it might have to do with the time.sleep but even increasing it from 0.5 didn't change the outcome. It seems as though it reaches a certain page and then cant move past it.